# Why am I not allowed to edit more questions than a mere 6-7?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

I see that I can't edit more than 6-7 questions/answers at a time and any further edits are totally grayed out until the prior edits are either approved or rejected or overridden by other's edits.

Can I get to know if there are any privileges that I need to earn for this?

Is there a limitation to do such a thing that I need to attain in my score on this site, I'm currently at score of 1400+.

And also I see that during the weekends in the [IST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) hours, question edits take more than six hours to be approved.

Comment: Restriction stops at [2000 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), restriction is there to prevent  early users to go on edit spree.

Comment: And you can only earn at most 1000 rep from accepted edits, so you can't get the privilege of making edits without review purely from edits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, until you have [2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (and your edits no longer require review), you can only have at most **5 pending edits**. This is to prevent the size of Suggested Edits queue from getting out of hand.

See [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) on Meta Stack Exchange, and [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416/rate-limit-suggested-edits) for the rationale behind this limit.

> And also I see that during the weekends in the IST hours, question edits take more than 6 hours to be approved.

I suppose that at those times, there aren't that many reviewers active, so you have to wait a little bit longer.